# Is an online game that is totally playable as pen and pencil or card game allowed?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Strategic Tic Tac Toe is a computer game where you effectively a game somewhat similar to Tic Tac Toe- the computer aspects of the actual game as totally replicable as an offline game. And there are others where the computer games are totally doable as offline. Judging by this question the answer is yes. 
 [Are questions specifically about the computer version of a game on topic?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1193/are-questions-specifically-about-the-computer-version-of-a-game-on-topic)

Comment: That version isn't just a computer game: https://mathwithbaddrawings.com/2013/06/16/ultimate-tic-tac-toe/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, questions about that game would be allowed. Our criteria for whether something counts as a "board or card game" for are purposes are that the game must

1. Be playable on or around a table
2. Have objective rules of play and win conditions
3. Offer dynamic challenges, either through other players, randomization, or both

   4. Be playable by hand, by human players implementing all of the rules

It doesn't matter whether you *actually* play the game by hand on a table and implement all of the rules. As long as it's possible to do so, asking about the game and any software implementation is allowed.